# Regex for capturing combinations =19 ,19

Tags: regex, unix, search, integer

I need a pattern to match on all the lines below except the last 3. I would think this would do it but nothing matches. Any suggestions? Basically I'm looking for the number 19 on it's own line, after a =, or after/before/between comma.

My try :

```
^[[:space:]]*[=,]*19[[:space:],]
```

Input file :

```
19
 19
=19
 =19
= 19
 = 19
,19
, 19
 ,19
 , 19
19,
19, 
19 ,
19 , 
,19,
,19 ,
,19, 
,19 , 
, 19,
 ,19,
 , 19,
 ,19 ,
, 19 ,
 , 19 ,
 ,19, 
, 19, 
 , 19, 
, 19 , 
 ,19 , 
 , 19 , 
=1999
19999
,9999
```

Comment: make the last class optional with `*` and add an end-of-line anchor `$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your regular expression as follows.

```
^[[:space:]=,]*19[[:space:],]*$
```

[**Explanation**](http://regexdoc.com/re/explain.pl?re=%5E%5B%5B%3Aspace%3A%5D%3D%2C%5D*19%5B%5B%3Aspace%3A%5D%2C%5D*%24&.submit=Explain%21&mode=SO&.cgifields=mode) | [**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/kQ5yD6/1)

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks! I also modified it to this to anticipate any punctuation. ^[[:space:][:punct:]]*19[[:space:][:punct:]]*$

Answer (score 0):

Some snippets with regexes using *word boundaries*

with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl)  :

```
$ perl -ne '/\b19\b/ and print' file
```

with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
$ awk '/\y19\y/{print}' file
```

with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) :

```
$ sed -n '/\b19\b/p' file
```

with [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) :

```
$ grep -P '\b19\b' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Negating the regular expression works.

```
!?19[^\d]
```

Test on http://regexpal.com/